# Cut text and add ellipses when TextView is overlapping another TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I am trying to build a chat cell layout like in Facebook messenger for android. I am able to replicate this layout easily. I added a maxLine parameter to the name in case it is really long and it will show ellipsis if it is the case. The issue is that if the name of the person is really long, Ellipsis will not appear and my timestamp will be 2 character long by 2 characters [TextView that shows the timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdhGN.png). I am also using the CirceImageView library.

**Build.graddle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bob"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:border_width="0dp"
        app:border_color="#FF000000"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/lblMessageTime"
                android:text="Person name is lonnnnnnnnnnnnnng"
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textTime"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="23:00"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/person_name"
                android:id="@+id/lblMessageTime"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/grayAddSessionButton"
            android:id="@+id/textMessage"
            android:text="This is a message"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to do this easily. I remove android:layout_weight="1" to the timestamp and I added android:layout_weight=".5" to the name TextView. Since the name TextView is the only one with a weight and it's  lower than 1, the TextView containing the name will not be fully shown if it's overlapping the timestamp [(see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnFUM.png).

Here is the new code:

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bob"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:border_width="0dp"
        app:border_color="#FF000000"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="This name is really long but it is cut"
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textTime"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:maxLines="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="23:00"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/lblMessageTime"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/grayAddSessionButton"
            android:id="@+id/textMessage"
            android:text="This is a message"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid ovelaping you should either not use `RelativeLayout` as container for your `TextViews` or not use `wrap_content` for `android:layout_width` of `person_name` `TextView` but make it fixed width (i.e. "200dp") or extend `TextView` class and make it disallow any streching beyond  certain width.

Comment: I also tried with a nested layout containing a linear layout that had the name and timestamp together. I put a layout_weight of 1 to the timestamp. It did not work as planned. Although it was not covered by the name , the timestamp was one character long and 5 characters high.